# How to implement the logical assignment in destructuring assignment in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

destructuring assignment doesn't work for the field in one object holds a falsy value, as follow:

```
let { aaa = 123 } = { aaa: null }
console.log(aaa) // null
```

so, how to achive `||=` in object destructuring assignment to implement such the field's destructed defalut value ? like this:

```
let { aaa ||= 123 } = { aaa: null }
console.log(aaa) // 123

// it equals to
// let aaa = ({ aaa: null }).aaa || 123
```

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: _"destructuring assignment doesn't work for the field in one object holds a falsy value"_ - `null` is still a value, so it works as expected. It's your requirement that isn't working with destructuring.

Comment: `let { aaa } = { aaa: null || 123 }`. Otherwise, you have to use your commented version. [Default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_values) only work with `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

So you cannot do what you are trying to do.

The destructuring assignment works as expected/specified. It is just that the default value only works when the destructured value is `undefined`.

You have to use the normal syntax for "falsy" values (***note**: this includes `undefined, false, 0, NaN` etc. Extensive list at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy*).

```
let { aaa } = { aaa: null }
aaa ||= 123;
```

---

Quoting from MDN [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_values)

*for objects*

> **Default values**
> A variable can be assigned a default, in the case that the value unpacked from the object is `undefined`.

*for arrays*

> **Default values**
> A variable can be assigned a default, in the case that the value unpacked from the array is `undefined`.

Comment: This is a non-answer to the question which was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default value in this way

```
let obj = null        
{ obj1 } = { obj1: obj || 123 }
```

OR

try assigning values to an object using a constructor. In that way the destructuring would work fine:

```
class Obj1 {
  a: string
  b: number
  constructor(obj) {
    this.a = obj && obj.a || 'default a'
    this.b = obj && obj.b || 1 
  }
}

let obj = null
let obj1 = new Obj1(obj)

let {aaa} = {aaa: obj1}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The default value is used when the property is not present, or has value undefined. It is not used if the property has value null.

[Destructuring - Default Value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_value)